# Angular JS Form Validation when the form is not active

Tags: angularjs

I am new to angular JS. I need help in the following case.

I am having an application which has a select box. It displays the list of products in the option. On changing the option, it displays different  forms and the forms are dynamic. It means if I create a new product then only the forms are created. Now I need a way to validate the form fields for both the forms.

But the problem is when I select the laptop form, product form becomes undefined and vice versa. How can I validate both the forms together on the button click.

Please help me on this.

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: The code is very big so I could not post it. The issue is on changing the option the previous form is replaced with a new form in the html. So when i check for the product1.$invalid it shows undefined. But it works for the product2.$invalid as that is currently the selected option.